# In spring-boot how to set BigQuery bean with Workload Identity k8s?

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, workload-identity

I have set in k8s setting the following Workload Identity:

```
spec.template.spec.serviceAccountName: wli-test
```

Then I set like this the BigQuery bean

```
@Bean
public BigQuery bigQueryService() {
    return BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
}
```

But everytime I try to call for example this method

```
bigquery.getTable(datasetName, tableName)
```

I get null as value, so it's loading correctly the bigquery bean.

In google documentation I didn't find anything.

Can someone please help me?

PS. if I try the same method with JSON service account I get correctly the table.

Comment: Do you have error code? 403? 401?

Comment: I get null, but if I use JSON service account I get the table.

Comment: And nothing in the logs? That's very strange. Either it works or not. Null isn't an error, it's Null!

Comment: I find the problem, the service account was in a project and the database in another, so I forget to set the correct projectId.

Comment: That makes sense.: The query worked (HTTP 200, no error) but didn't find the resource (wrong project).